# Relationship between transpose matrices and orthogonal complements

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have recently been introduced to the idea of orthogonal complements, and I am given a question to try to relate them. Suppose I have a subspace $V$ of $R^n$ and a square matrix **A** of order n, such that **$Av$** $\in$ *$V$* for all $v \in V$. How can I make use of this to show that for an orthogonal complement of $V^⊥$, $A^Tw \in V^⊥$ for all $w \in V^⊥$? I am at a complete loss... Does anyone have any advice or tips?

In addition, suppose that $V = span\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$. We have another matrix $B$ such that $u_1,u_2,...,u_k$ form the rows of $B$. How is it that the nullspace of $B$ is equal to $V^⊥$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are asked you show the following:

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that for all $v \in V$ we have $Av \in V$. Then for all $w \in V^{\perp}$, we have $A^{T} w \in V^{\perp}$.

PROOF: Let $v \in V$ $w \in V^{\perp}$. We need to show that $(A^T w) \cdot v = 0$

$$(A^T w) \cdot v=(A^T w)^T v=w^T A v=w \cdot (Av) = 0,$$

where we used that $w$ is orthogonal to $Av$ since $A \in V$ when $v \in V$.